# Where should my ERT tests go?

Tags: ert

I'm new to using ERT for testing my Elisp code, and I have a question that doesn't seem to be covered in the manual: according to best practices, where does one typically put the ERT tests? Do they go at the end of the elisp file that is to be tested, or should I put them in a separate file? I'm sure they'll work either way, but is one or the other preferred?

Comment: Please _never_ define test cases inline.  There's no need to force your tests upon end users.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that wasn't the answer, but I still wasn't sure what the convention was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would place the tests in a `test` directory and name it `thepackage-test.el`. Alternatively, `thepackage-test-onething.el` and `thepackage-test-anotherthing.el`.

Using a test directory is especially useful if the tests require auxiliary files.

Another advantage is that it simplifies the MELPA recipe, as subdirectories aren't included by default.

For an example of a package with relative complex tests, you can take a look at my font-lock rules for CMake: https://github.com/Lindydancer/cmake-font-lock

Comment: I used [this code](https://github.com/Lindydancer/cmake-font-lock/blob/47687b6ccd0e244691fb5907aaba609e5a42d787/test/cmake-font-lock-test-setup.el#L20-L27) from the package linked in the answer in order for the tests to be able to `require` the source files. Just putting that at the top of your test file (before any `require`s) should do it.

Answer (score 4):

Separate file, of course. The end users need not load it. In fact, if you distribute through MELPA, the tests won't be bundled.  The convention is to name the file `foo-test.el`.